# CryptoAPI (CryptEncrypt and CryptDecrypt) available under .net?

Tags: c#, .net

Does .net have these functions implementations?
Or do you know where I could download the unit from, which wraps these methods in a c# unit?

Thanks!

Comment: Sorry. I've wanted to have c# CryptEncrypt and CryptDecrypt implementation.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you are looking for [here](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/advapi32.cryptencrypt)

Comment: Yep indeed. CryptEncrypt and CryptDecrypt I am interested in. I ended up with PInvoking. I could only find in the internet structures definition and some constants, no more unformtunately.

Comment: this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5365965/pinvoking-adwapi-dll-cryptdecrypt-and-cryptencrypt-functions-weird-problem may point you in the right direction.